# PermissionError when loading fetch_20newsgroups from sklear.dataset

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
data = fetch_20newsgroups()
data.target_names
```

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\liu.h\scikit_learn_data\20news_home\20news-bydate-test\sci.crypt'

Comment: Do you have access to this directory?

Comment: i'm new to Python, how to have access to this directory or how to check?